# Unable to unlock luks from crypttab or key-file

Tags: encryption, luks

My home is stored in a luks partiton whose passphrase is stored on a usb key.

I have been using this setup for a few years and my home usually unlocks itself at boot from the following crypttab :

```
user@magicbook:~$ cat /etc/crypttab 
luks-home UUID=81ebf59e-a1a1-4f2c-a4b0-5675ea0ad7b2 /mnt/usbdata/tmpkey.txt nofail
```

However, a few weeks ago it stopped unlocking automatically and i now have to do it by hand.

Moreover, cryptsetup luksOpen --keyfile doesn't work whereas cat tmpkey.txt | cryptsetup luksOpen - works :

```
boss@magicbook:/home/user$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p8 luks-home --key-file /mnt/usbdata/tmpkey.txt
No key available with this passphrase.
boss@magicbook:/home/user$ sudo cat /mnt/usbdata/tmpkey.txt | sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p8 luks-home –
boss@magicbook:/home/user$
```

What went wrong and how can i get back automatic unlocking ?

```
user@magicbook:~$ cryptsetup -V
cryptsetup 2.4.3

user@magicbook:~$ uname -a
Linux magicbook 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks